# How to prove that $\omega_1 \leq \mathfrak p$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

I am trying to understand the stated above Theorem. $\mathfrak p$ is the smallest cardinality of any family $\mathcal F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$, which has the strong finite intersection property, but does not have a pseudo intersection. The definitions are:

A family $\mathcal F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$, has the **strong finite intersection property** if every finite subfamily has infinite intersection. Also, a **pseudo intersection** of a family $\mathcal F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$, is an infinite subset of $\omega$ which is almost contained in every member of $\mathcal F$.
Where $A$ is **Almost contained** in $B$ means that for all except maybe a finite number of elements in $A$, $a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B$. Also, $[\omega]^\omega$ is the space of all infinite subsets of $\omega$.

I have a Proof of the theorem (see below), which I somehow don't manage to understand. I don't understand who is $a_0$? Is $X_0$ an infinite sequence from $[\omega]^\omega$?

Thank you,
Shir

---

The following proof is quoted from Halbeisen's book Combinatorial Set Theory, [page 181](http://books.google.com/books?id=NZVb54INnywC&pg=PA181). The book is freely available on [author's website](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/publications.html).

> Theorem 8.1. $\omega_1\le\mathfrak p$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $\mathscr E=\{X_n\in[\omega]^\omega : n\in\omega\}$ be a countable family which has the *sfip*.
>   We construct a pseudo-intersection of $\mathscr E$ as follows: 
>   Let $a_0:=\bigcap X_0$ and for positive $n$ let
>   $$a_n=\bigcap \left(\bigcap \{X_i; i\in n\}\setminus \{a_i; i\in n\}\right).$$
>   Further, let  $Y=\{a_n : n\in\omega\}$; then for every $n\in\omega$, $Y\setminus \{a_i; i\in n\} \subseteq X_n$ which shows that $Y\subseteq^* X_n$, hence, $Y$ is a pseudointersection of $\mathscr E$.

Comment: $a_0 = \bigcap X_0$ is the least member of $X_0$. It is a poor way of writing.

Comment: Yes, not the ideal notation, but, it made me learn somethng new.. :) Thank you!

Comment: I think it is good practice to mention also the origin of the problem. In this case, you were studying Halbeisen's book Combinatorial Set Theory.
Here is Google Books link to [page 181](http://books.google.com/books?id=NZVb54INnywC&pg=PA181). 
The books seems also to be freely available [on website](http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?ve_vo_det&key2=1501) of a course taught by the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $\omega_1\leq\frak p$ it suffices to show that $\omega\neq\frak p$. That is, given a countable family with strong finite intersection property, it must have a pseudo-intersection.

So suppose that $\{X_n\in[\omega]^\omega\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a family with the strong finite intersection property, we define $a_0=\min X_0$, which for ordinals is the same as $\bigcap X_0$. Next we define $$a_n = \min\left\{m\in\omega\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{} m\in\bigcap_{k<n}X_n\setminus\{a_k\mid k<n\}\right\}$$

Finally we claim that $Y=\{a_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is a pseudo intersection of our $X_n$'s because for every $n\in\omega$, $Y\setminus\{a_k\mid k<n\}$ is a subset of $X_n$ (recall how $a_n$ was chosen).